# Internet Explorer canvas issues with excanvas on multiple drawings?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, excanvas

So Im running canvas to draw tides and it works perfect on FF, Safari, etc but as always IE 8 fails…

I implemented excanvas and it works a little bit on the first element and it dies…

http://munging.us/tideGraph/www/tidegraph.html

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hm? http://l.paulbgd.me/1h7iqZ5 http://l.paulbgd.me/1h7itnE

Comment: They look awfully similar to me.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention Im testing on IE 8

Answer (score -1):

Internet Explorer 8 does not support the Canvas element.

http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie-8.html

Comment: You are right, but in question aboveб mentioned EXCANVAS, it is canvas emulating via VML